# How to get a child element to change on hover over parent element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to get the `width` and `height` of the image `#add-cc-img` when hovering over the parent element `#add-new-cc` + `.credit-card`. How can I keep the parent's `width` and `height` to remain in its original form and only change the size of the image?

```css
.credit-card {
  border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  width: 30%;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 3% 20px 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.credit-card-inner {
  margin: 25px;
}
#add-new-cc {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
}
#add-new-cc:hover,
#add-cc-img {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
}
#add-new-cc-title {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
#add-cc-img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="credit-card" id="add-new-cc">
  <div class="credit-card-inner">
    <h3 class="blue sans-pro" id="add-new-cc-title">Add New Card</h3>
    <img src="images/add-circle.png" alt="Add New Credit Card" id="add-cc-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform: scale`, it will resize the image in a much better (looking) way

*(and remove the comma in `#add-new-cc:hover #add-cc-img { ... }`)*

I added `transition: .5s;` to the `#add-cc-img { ... }` rule, so it will animate on un-hover as well.

```css
.credit-card {
  border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  width: 30%;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 3% 20px 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.credit-card-inner {
  margin: 25px;
}
#add-new-cc {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
}
#add-new-cc-title {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
#add-cc-img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: .5s;
}
#add-new-cc:hover #add-cc-img {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  transition: .5s;
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="credit-card" id="add-new-cc">
  <div class="credit-card-inner">
    <h3 class="blue sans-pro" id="add-new-cc-title">Add New Card</h3>
    <img src="images/add-circle.png" alt="Add New Credit Card" id="add-cc-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. the transform definitely makes the image look better.

Comment: The `transform: scale()` idea helped me improve a bunch of buttons on a site I'm developing. Along with `transition`, the buttons are now more attractive and elegant on hover. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks for letting me know, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

it seems you don't need to use comma here: #add-new-cc:hover, #add-cc-img . Without comma it seems to work as it should

```css
.credit-card {
  border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  width: 30%;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 3% 20px 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.credit-card-inner {
  margin: 25px;
}
#add-new-cc {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
}
#add-new-cc:hover
#add-cc-img {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
}
#add-new-cc-title {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
#add-cc-img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="credit-card" id="add-new-cc">
  <div class="credit-card-inner">
    <h3 class="blue sans-pro" id="add-new-cc-title">Add New Card</h3>
    <img src="images/add-circle.png" alt="Add New Credit Card" id="add-cc-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you put a comma between selectors, you are creating a list of different selectors that will execute one rule. This is what you have:

```
#add-new-cc:hover, #add-cc-img {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
}
```

Instead, you need a descendant selector to make this work (replace the comma with a space):

```
#add-new-cc:hover #add-cc-img {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  transition: .5s;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
}
```

```css
.credit-card {
  border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  width: 30%;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 3% 20px 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.credit-card-inner {
  margin: 25px;
}
#add-new-cc {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
}
#add-new-cc:hover #add-cc-img {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  transition: .5s;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
}
#add-new-cc-title {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
#add-cc-img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="credit-card" id="add-new-cc">
  <div class="credit-card-inner">
    <h3 class="blue sans-pro" id="add-new-cc-title">Add New Card</h3>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt="Add New Credit Card" id="add-cc-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is webkit for transition obsolete now?